# Centralize content inside a percentage-based div

Tags: html, css

I'm probably disconsidering something pretty obvious, but anyway.

I got a set of 6 `<iframe>` elements divided in 2 rows of 3 columns. The problem here is that even considering a width of 100% for the parent `<div>`, establishing `width: 30%;` for each iframe + a `left-margin: 1%;` (gutter) + `left-margin: 4%;` just for the first `iframe` in each row still doesn't centralize the whole block.

Ideas?

```css
#portfolio {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

#portfolio > h2 {
font-family: "Optima LT Std Italic";
font-size: 2.625em;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 1%; 
}

.presentation {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 1%;
background-color:#DE6F71; /*Just for a better visualization during the development*/
}

iframe {
display: inline-block;
width: 30%;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.noLeftMargin {
margin-left: 4%;   
}
```

```html
<body>
    
     <section id="portfolio">
        
         <h2>Portfolio</h2>
            <h3>Websites</h3>
         <h3>Audio</h3>
            
           <div class="presentation">
    
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk" allowfullscreen class="noLeftMargin"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk" class="noLeftMargin"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>

           </div>
          
        </section>
    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a `text-align: center` to the parent div. This will center all the `iframe` elements since they are `inline-block`
- Remove everywhere the `.noLeftMargin` class
- to the `iframe` elements assign `margin: 0 .5% 1% .5%;` so the left and right margin are the same and the horizontal space is balanced.
- to the parent add `padding: 0 3.5%` and remove the width (the div will take the available space)

the result is

```
(3.5% 
+ 0.5%) + <iframe> + (0.5% +
+ 0.5%) + <iframe> + (0.5% +
+ 0.5%) + <iframe> + (0.5% +
+ 3.5%)
```

that is

```
4% + iframe + 1% + iframe + 1% + iframe + 4%
```

please note that `inline-block` elements could show some extra space in between, but this is a their well-known behaviour and many answer on this topic can be found here on SO

```css
#portfolio {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}


.presentation {
   margin: 1% 0 0 0;
   padding: 0 3.5%;
   background-color:#DE6F71; 
   text-align:center;
}

iframe {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 30%;
   margin : 0 .5% 1% .5%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
   <section id="portfolio">

    <div class="presentation">
    
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk" ></iframe>
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
   </div>
          
</section>
    
</body>
```

Comment: It has centralized the whole block of iframes, but I don't want the left and right margins on the edges to be 1% like the space separating them, that's why I was using the .noLeftMargin class for the first iframe of each row.

The idea would be 30% for each iframe, 1% separating the ones in the center from the ones on the edge and some 4% margin for the left and right edges.

Comment: it's not really clear to me what would be the visual effect you'd like to achieve: could you update your question with an image of the final result?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add an image as I've just started to use the forum and still need to gain some more reputation to unlock it. Let me try to put it in another way. In brief, iframes on the edges must have margins of 4% (left margin for the left edge and right margin for the right edge). Just the space between the central iframes (1 in each column) should be 1%.

Comment: @JGSouthern see my update: I've inserted a `padding: 0 3.5%` to the parent div, while the iframe has `margin : 0 .5% 1% .5%;`

Comment: that's the math I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

I guess you want something like this:

1) **Removed noLeftMargin** Class, as was messing your marigns

2) Added **padding:0% 2.2%;** for presentation class.

3) Added **margin-left:1% 2.2%;** for iframes.

[WORKING:DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLbZZj?editors=110)

```css
#portfolio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#portfolio > h2 {
    font-family:"Optima LT Std Italic";
    font-size: 2.625em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1%;
}
.presentation {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding:0% 2.2%;
    background-color:#DE6F71;
    /*Just for a better visualization during the development*/
}
iframe {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolio">
     <h2>Portfolio</h2>

     <h3>Websites</h3>

     <h3>Audio</h3>

    <div class="presentation">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk" ></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpsVY_jsGWk"></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```